# how to get list of paired bluetooth devices that are power off or not is range in UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, bluetooth

I want to get the list of paired devices that are not in range or power off. I am doing in Xamarin forms UWP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the list of paired devices that are not in range or power off. I am doing in Xamarin forms UWP

If you want to get the paired Bluetooth data from Xamarin platform side, we suggest you use [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to approach, make device watcher in uwp client and callback the paired list data to Xamarin side.

For getting paired Bluetooth device. please refer official code sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs/Scenario4_Snapshot.xaml.cs#L18). For callback data with `DependencyService` please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#universal-windows-platform).

Comment: I have already achieved paired list of devices and now my requirement is how I can identify the devices that are switched off or not in discoverable range.

Comment: currently, there is no such api could detect the device is power off or out discoverable range. but you could try to connect it manually, if has timeout exception or connect failed,  it means that the device is power off or out of range